# Intersection of two list in N time

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists `(['a', 's', 'f', 'f', 's'], ['f', 'f', 'a', 's'])`. The required output is `['a','s','f','f']`. The output should give the intersection of two lists. The arrangement of characters in the output list is according to the order of occurrence in the first list `['a', 's', 'f', 'f', 's']`.

How can I implement this in python? I have already done this in N**2 time. Is it possible to do this in N time?
My current solution:

```
def com(string1, string2):
    string2_list=list(string2)
    store=""
    for check in string1:
        for i,v in enumerate(string2_list):
            if v==check:
                store=store+check
                del(string2_list[i])
    return store
```

Comment: So what is your current solution?

Comment: Because the dupe isn't concerned with `O(N)`, that seems to be the crucial part of this question

Comment: I don't think you can go below O(NlogN) honestly.. We will see the answers

Comment: This is not a duplicate from the linked question. This case includes ordering, the other one doesn't.

Comment: Creating counters is O(N) each (you need to iterate each list), set intersection is linear with constant set lookup, so you get 3*N at most.

Comment: See the question 'Characters in Strings in Python' at http://thereq.com/q/best-python-software-interview-questions/google

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter`'s built-in intersection operation.

```
>>> l1, l2 = (['a', 's', 'f', 'f', 's'], ['f', 'f', 'a', 's'])
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(l1) & collections.Counter(l2)
Counter({'f': 2, 'a': 1, 's': 1})
```

From here it is not hard to build a suitable list:

```
>>> counter = collections.Counter(l1) & collections.Counter(l2)
>>> out = list(counter.elements())
>>> print out
['a', 's', 'f', 'f']
```

Or, to order according to one of the lists:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for k in l1:
...     if counter[k] > 0:
...         counter[k] -= 1
...         out.append(k)
...
>>> print out
['a', 's', 'f', 'f']
```

This is expected-time O(N): Counter creation is expected O(N) time, and counter intersection is expected O(N) time as well. ​

Comment: shouldn't the `counter` in the final example be just `Counter(l2)` rather than the sum?

Comment: Sice counter is an unordered collection, shouldn't building the ordered list take theta(NlogN)?

Comment: @wim: it doesn't actually matter, really. I've done it this way because it feels more right.

Comment: @BlackBear: We build the ordered list according to the ordering in `l1`, which is already sorted the way we want. So there's no "log n" penalty here.

Comment: hmm, `&` on counters is intersection (`min(counter1[k], counter2[k]`) which I don't think  is appropriate here

Comment: @wim: Yes, it is; `&` is "multiset intersection" which is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Hmm, I beg to differ.. for input `l1 = 'aab'` and `l2 = 'aaab'`, your output give different results than the OP own implementation

Comment: @wim: It produces `aab`. What do you expect it to output?

Comment: assuming they want the result from the code in question, `'aaab'`

Comment: although this is not caused by the multiset intersection!  :)

Comment: @wim: based on their question, I rather think that `aaab` output is a bug with the OP's program. (Note that in `asffs/ffas` the output has only one `s`, consistent with multiset intersection)

Answer (score 1):

This works using the counter from the collections:

```
import collections

a = ['a', 's', 'f', 'f', 's']
b = collections.Counter(['f', 'f', 'a', 's'])

output = []
for x in a:
    if b.get(x):
        output.append(x)
        b.subtract(x)

print output
```

Result:

```
['a', 's', 'f', 'f']
```

Not a 100% certain about the algorithmic complexity here but my guess is that a lookup within a counter is `O(1)` (hash based) which makes this `O(n)`.

Comment: Can anyone explain the -1 here?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a dictionary to lookup the order of an l1 item rather than the index method of l1:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1, l2 = (['a', 's', 'f', 'f', 's'], ['f', 'f', 'a', 's'])
>>> l1_to_index = {val: indx for indx, val in reversed(list(enumerate(l1)))}
>>> sorted((Counter(l1) & Counter(l2)).elements(), key=lambda x: l1_to_index[x])
['a', 's', 'f', 'f']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the lists, which would give you:
List1: "affss"
List2: "affs".
Then use a string matching loop

Pseudocode (slight adjustments might be needed)

```
list1;
list2;
list3; //output list
n = list1.length() //list1 length
x = list2.length() //list2 length
int i = 0; //list1 counter
int j = 0; //list2 counter
//go through both list simutainously and remove the lexographically smallest at every list1[i] != list2[j]
while i != n and j != x
    if list1[i] == list[j]
        list3.add(list1(i))
        i++
        j++
    else
        if list1[i]<=list[j]
            i++;
        else
            j++
return list3
```

Algorithm Cost:
Sorting = O(nlgn)
Use mergesort for the ease, or if you can get your hands on a randomized quicksort, the quicksort is ursually 3 times faster, should be a part of your python lib, if not: http://randalgos.blogspot.dk/2012/03/randomized-quick-sort-in-python.html
The while loop will take 2n at max, leaving you with:

O(nlgn) + 2n = O(nlgn)